# How many pages, not frames, have been already generated before the current one?

Tags: beamer, luatex

Using `LuaLaTeX` to generate a `Beamer` presentation, at some point, I have to know (on the Lua side) how many pages (not frames) have already been generated before the current one?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\directlua{

    for i = 1 , math.random (1 , 5) do
    tex.print (
    "\\begin{frame}" ..
    "frame " .. i ..  " could complex with overlays" ..
    "\\end{frame}" )
    end
    
    tex.print (
    "\\begin{frame}" ..
    " How many pages, not frames, have been generated before this one? " ..
    "\\end{frame}" )
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: something like `tex.count["c@page"]` should work, but you will have to split the code over two \directlua imho.

Comment: thank you, I just saw this solution. No need to split, the beamer pdf is generated by a standalone lua file called by a \directlua. Thank you. Feel free to write an answer.